# Getting server data for the Apple Watch

Tags: ios, watchkit, nsurlsession, apple-watch, watchos-2

I am wondering how to go about designing a watchOS app that depends on getting the latest feed from a server. Would you need to use application context and just have the iPhone push it over in the background using the WatchConnectivity framework or would you use NSURLSession on the Apple Watch itself? Keep in mind this is for watchOS 2.

Answer (score 0):

You can use NSURLSession to handle your request. So your request would be native on your watchn. But note that your watch is there to show simple Content to the user.

Comment: @BilaReffas have any demo example for SERVER API call ?? please give any suggestion for this